# React Class this.ref.current.scrollIntoView not scrolling when it should

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class which is rendered by a navigation bar parent class when the user clicks an a navbar link. I want that child class to scroll into view. My code is:

```
import "./mainpage.css"
import containers from "../../resources/containers.jpg"
import React from "react"

class MainPage extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            componentMounted: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({componentMounted: true})
        console.log("hihi")
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView();
        }, 600)
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.componentMounted) {
            return (
                <div className = {`main-page`}>
                <img src = {containers} className = "main-image-containers"/> 
                    <div className = "main-page-text-elements">
                        <p className = "main-page-text rtl">
                        </p>
                        <p className = "main-page-text rtl">
                        </p>                  
                        <p className = "main-page-text rtl">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

}

export default MainPage
```

When the user clicks the nav, which renders this child, the elements in the class renders, a timeout function runs to give the class time to render the elements and then scroll them into view.
However the function gives me an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

When I try to check if this.myRef exists:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    // window.scroll(0,600)
    if (this.myRef.current) {
        this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView();
    }
}, 1000)
```

nothing get's scrolled. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `ref` attribute to your element like this:

```
<div ref={this.myRef}></div>
```